# How to format filepath with spaces in Mac OSX C++

Tags: c++, macos, filepath, stat, getcwd

I am trying to use the `stat()` function in a C++ program I'm writing for Mac OS X.

the stat() function fails to find this directory:

```
/Users/devuser/git/thisprogram/build/Release/ABC USER Testing App.app/Contents/Resources
```

But it is able to find this one:

```
/Users/devuser/git/thisprogram/build/Release/Resources
```

I am guessing it has something to do with spaces.  I got the directory from the `getcwd()` command.  I even trying surrounding it with quotes but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: [tag:c] isn't [tag:c++]. Please use appropriate tags.

Comment: Show your code and include some logging of the path string from a run.